# Poping the backstack without causing illegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

I was getting
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

in my code and i searched  statckoverflow i got the below code as solution.

Now i am not getting  IllegalStateException but the problem is.. below code is clearing the entire stacktrace. but i want to pop only the last transaction/entry in the backstack. how to do that??

```
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
```

How to pop only the last transaction/entry in the backstack??

Code of how i am adding to stack:

```
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
                setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).
                replace(R.id.content_frame, pageFragment, currentItem).
                addToBackStack(currentItem).
                commit();
```

Comment: Post your fragment adding code plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pop up the last transaction entry:

```
int last = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry entry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(last);
String tag = entry.getName();
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("last");  //get the last fragment
```

Also during transaction you have to add tag..

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("last");
```

You can also use [popBackStackImmediate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to pop up the last fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(last), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

To pop fragment from BackStack using tag use:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack ("last", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: thanks for the replay...                                                                                           the last in the line   getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(last), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);                                is the int variable and not   string  "last"...                                                      so can you please tell how to pop backstack with   tag  "last"

Answer (score 1):

For this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

instead of `commit()`, use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` and problem will be gone. Then use your desired approach.

Comment: I will use  commitAllowingStateLoss()  and i will pop the last entry using getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();     so will i not get IllegalStateException  after doing soo??

Comment: No, you will not. Let me know about the outcome.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of state loss when popping the back stack. The checkStateLoss() method is called in FragmentManager prior to executing this action(popping the back stack).